# Concurrent Scheduled method in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a spring application which has two classes annotated with @Component, in each class, I have a method annotated with @Scheduled, that means I want to run those methods at the fixed interval like this :

This is First Component which has a readFirstComponent() method, this methos read something from somewhere and it takes awhile to carries out, 
    @Component
public class FirstComp {

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000 )
public void readFirstComponent() {
    // body
}
```

//other methods
}

Second component almost doing the same as First Component does,

```
@Component
```

public class SecondComp {

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000 )
public void readSecondComponent() {
    // body
}
```

//other methods
}

I have a runner class to start the application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/Spring-AutoScan.xml")
public class Application {
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);    
}
```

}

When I start the application FirtComp is starting and readFirstComponent() carrying out after nearly 14s coming to the end  THEN readSecondComponent() from SecondComp is starting, and so on,
My problem is that I want to start both methods concurrently, please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 5):

By default there is only one thread to run scheduling tasks.

You could read about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling) and find out how to configure the scheduler to get a pool with more threads.

> 27.4.1 Enable scheduling annotations
>
> To enable support for @Scheduled and @Async annotations add @EnableScheduling and @EnableAsync to one of your @Configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
}
```

> You are free to pick and choose the relevant annotations for your application. For example, if you only need support for @Scheduled, simply omit @EnableAsync. For more fine-grained control you can additionally implement the SchedulingConfigurer and/or AsyncConfigurer interfaces. See the javadocs for full details.
>
> If you prefer XML configuration use the  element.

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

> Notice with the above XML that an executor reference is provided for handling those tasks that correspond to methods with the @Async annotation, and the scheduler reference is provided for managing those methods annotated with @Scheduled.

Since you use annotations to configure you beans it would be better to `implement the SchedulingConfigurer`.

Like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureTasks(
  ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
}
}
```

Comment: Please also copy the most relevant part from the link, because links tend to be removed.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for that information. I will improve my answering skills.

Answer (score 4):

Old question but I was dealing with this myself. I could not use the provided solution above, because I needed to ensure only one instance of each method was running at a time. And increasing default schedule threadPool size meant I could end up in trouble if methods took longer than shcedule interval.

So instead I created 2 thread pools of a single thread each, and then annotate each method to use the relevant thread pool (i.e. single thread).

Creating the thread pools:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MainApplication.class);   
        application.run(args);
    }       

    @Bean("schedulePool1")
    public Executor jobPool() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        exec.setCorePoolSize(1);
        exec.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        exec.setQueueCapacity(10);
        exec.setThreadNamePrefix("first-");
        exec.initialize();
        return exec;
    }       

    @Bean("schedulePool2")
    public Executor jobPool2() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        exec.setCorePoolSize(1);
        exec.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        exec.setQueueCapacity(10);
        exec.setThreadNamePrefix("second-");
        exec.initialize();
        return exec;
    }
}
```

Then you can add the `@Async` annotation to your two sheduled methods.

```
@Async("schedulePool1")
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000 )
public void readFirstComponent() {
    // body
}
```

And

```
@Async("schedulePool2")
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000 )
public void readSecondComponent() {
    // body
}
```

Then in your logs you should see stuff with correct `[thread]`:

```
2020-02-21 20:47:01 [first-1] INFO  sodved.JobSchedule - running readFirstComponent
...
2020-02-21 20:47:01 [second-1] INFO  sodved.JobService - running readSecondComponent
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: what if you don't used `Async` annotation and just set the pool size to number of components? In case of two components => `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=2`. You also need to use `fixDelay` instead of `fixRate` to have interval period just after previous completion, so no issue if a method takes longer than interval

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani then the same method can run twice at the same time

Comment: @flup Never! Suppose there are two threads and two different methods. Having the same fixDelay in addition to the blocking method calls (Synch) guarantees that.

Comment: Ah. Yes. I overlooked the fixedDelay part.